# Boost ASIO TCP timer client error "resolve: The specified class is not found"

Tags: c++, tcp, resolve

I am following Boost's TCP Timer tutorial [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime1/src.html)
 to learn TCP and UDP.  I comment out the argc check, and change the following line:

```
tcp::resolver::query query(argv[1], "daytime");
```

into:

```
tcp::resolver::query query("127.0.0.1", "daytime");
```

Having the [server code](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime2/src.html)
 run on the same machine, I then ran the client code.  This error is thrown:

```
resolve: The specified class is not found
```

Using the debugger, the error comes from this line:

```
tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
```

which is right below the query declaration.  Can someone point me to where the error comes from, and how to fix it?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer.  The server code specified port number 13.  I just need to change the line:

```
tcp::resolver::query query("127.0.0.1", "daytime");
```

into:

```
tcp::resolver::query query("127.0.0.1", "13");
```